# ActiveMQ Server startup stuck at "Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' "

Tags: activemq-classic

This is the first time I am attempting to start the ActiveMQ JMS Provider on my machine, & it gets stuck while starting, at ( **"Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'** ). I set the JAVa_HOME env variables before attempting to start the server. What have i missed?

Comment: That is probably insufficient to debug this, can you provide any log files being generated / conf files in use?

Comment: **2014-01-14 17:28:53,093 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: Using access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml | /hawtio | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2014-01-14 17:28:53,734 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://localhost:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2014-01-14 17:28:53,937 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | WrapperSimpleAppMain** This is where the process stops, the server does not start and it gets stuck at this point.

Comment: In my experience the stock ActiveMQ config starts fine on Windows and Linux. How exactly are you trying to start the server (which script) and have you verified that all ports configured in `activemq.xml` and `jetty.xml` are free? Have you made any changes in either of the two?

Comment: no I have not made any changes in either of the two files. I tried to start it by running the activemq.bat file from the location to which I unzipped the download. ( in the manner shown on ActiveMQ website, from DOS Command prompt)

Comment: I just downloaded the 5.9.0 release and gave it a spin. I think you are not having a problem at all. The `Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'` message is simply the last thing the server prints when it is done with start-up. I was able to access the web console under `http://localhost:8161/` after that.

Comment: oh....well that was a real googly then :(...anyway, thanq very much Ralf for clearing it up....!!! :)